# Error importing HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, themes, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

First of all, I am new with Android.
I am doing an app, and I am  implementing a library called [HoloEverywhere](http://holoeverywhere.com/).
This library use in the themes.xml the library ActionBar Sherlock. I have imported to my workspace ActionBar Sherlock and I have added it to HoloEverywhere.
Next, I have added HoloEverywhere to my project, but when I try to use it, I have an error (I tried to use a button):

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.ButtonHolo (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse.
```

I put the path of the class in my layout, like this:

```
<com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.ButtonHolo
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text" />
```

How I can solve this problem and use this library in my project?. Thanks :)
PS. Sorry for my english, I know it is not very good.

Comment: Hello, I am Christophe (or Waza_be) and this is the first time I have seen such an error! If I found something, I will come and answer you!

Comment: i do up steps but i get this error on pom.xml file : Multiple annotations found at this line: - Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:1.0 from http:// repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:1.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/ maven2): The operation was cancelled. - Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20895081/623694

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Follow the steps below(taken from blog [here](http://androidfragments.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-to-use-actionbar-sherlock.html)) to add `ActionBarSherlock`**

1. [Download](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) the .zip/.tgz and extract it
2. Go to eclipse and choose `File->New-> Android Project`
3. Select `Create project from existing source` and then `browse` to the `library` folder inside extracted `AndroidBarSherlock` folder
4. Build Target should be the latest(14 or15), but your minSdkVersion can be less (7 or 8)
5. Press `Finish`
6. Right click on the newly created project and go to `Properties`.
7. Under the `Android` heading, you should see a section for `Library` with a checkbox `IsLibrary`. Make sure that's checked.
8. Right click -> Properies on the project in which you wish to add `AndroidBarSherlock`  under the `Android` heading and the `Library` section choose `Add`.
9. You should see the `ActionBarSherlock` library, add this to your project
10. Lastly, if you were using the *compatibility support* , you need to delete that *jar* since it's included in ActionBarSherlock.

**Follow the steps below to add [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)**

1. [Download](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) Zip from GitHub to your computer
2. UnZip the folder
3. Go to eclipse and choose `File->New-> Android Project`
4. Select `Create project from existing source` and then `browse` to the `HoloEverywhereLib` folder inside extracted folder
5. Press `Finish`
6. Right click on the newly created project and go to `Properties`.
7. Under the `Android` heading, you should see a section for `Library` with a checkbox `IsLibrary`. Make sure that's checked and press `Add` and previously added library `ActionBarSherlock`.

**Follow these steps to add `HoloEverywhere` to your project**

1. Create a new Android project
2. Right Click on project -> Properties -> Android -> Add, add both `ActionBarSherlock` and `HoloEverywhere`
3. Change the `Android Manifest` to following

   `<application
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme">`
4. Edit you `main.xml` to include Holo theme widgets.
5. Change your `activity` as follows

   ```
   public class ChkActionBarSherlock extends SherlockActivity {
       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: :i followed your steps for holo every where but it shows error on Dialogholo.java  on this lines View customView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.alert_dialog_holo,
    null);
  mTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle); R can not be resolved error,Holoalertdialogbuilder.java in this files error is on this line   mTitle = (TextView) customTitle.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
   FontLoader.loadFont(mTitle, FontLoader.ROBOTO_REGULAR);
   mIcon = (ImageView) customTitle.findViewById(R.id.icon);
   setCustomTitle(customTitle);

Comment: You problem looks like `R can not be resolved`. Clean you project and trying googling for the error. Lots of data on this on Web.

Comment: :I tried every thing nothing worked.When i import holoeverywhere lib to eclipse only,i get all this errors

Comment: :In this Follow these steps to add HoloEverywhere to your project ,can you explain step 4 and 5,i did n't under stand.

Comment: Make sure that you have "Compiler compliance level" set to 1.6. Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Compiler comliance level.

Comment: I think the theme that changed name to: Holo.Theme.Sherlock.Light

Comment: @JohanB You have to add a theme in Android Manifest, see which one works for you  `android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock"`

Comment: Yes but from what I can see in the latest version there is no theme called Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock, I use Holo.Theme.Sherlock.Light.

Comment: The answer of **[coding crow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/932307/coding-crow)** is very useful BUT there is a missing step in the "" paragraph: The library **android-support-v4** in the "*libs*" folder of ActionSherlock projet should be removed and replaced by **android-support-v4-r13.jar** present in HoloEverywhere zip folder.

Comment: i have tons of errors with the library after i've downloaded both the HoloEverywhere (v1.6.1) and the ActionBarSherlock library (v4.3.1) . only the actionBarSherlock has the android-support-v4.jar file. what is going on?

Comment: never mind. i've fixed it by choosing "add support library" to the actionBarSherlock library. now what i need is to learn how to use this library. hopefully it won't be hard. i hope my fix is correct though.

Comment: Hi.. This has worked for me in the past. But just realised that this does not work now for the latest version of holoeverywhere..https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere
One needs to use egit for eclipse, which does not work for eclipse juno

Comment: @ambit You can still download the zip file from Prototik Holoeverywhere git repo.

Comment: But doing it by these steps gives and error like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278884/holoeverywhere-error-build-path-contains-duplicate-entry-src

Comment: @ambit Ask a separate question,clearly mention your problem with links and images also you can look at IntelliJ Idea CE IDE for Android.

Comment: Does this still work?  On step 7 for adding HoloEverywhere, where ABS is added as a library to HoloEverywhere, I get about 1000 `error: Attribute "<whatever attribute>" has already been defined`.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal, thanks for the fast response!  So I have the two library projects (ABS and HoloEverywhere) in my workspace.  Neither knows about the other, ie, ABS is not being used by HoloEverywhere.  I  create a blank Android project.  Adding either library project is fine, but as soon as I add both, I get those `error: Attribute "<...>" has already been defined` errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: @nissemand HoloEverywhere uses ABS. ABS does not use HoloEverywhere.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal, I figured it out!  I was using the latest version of HoloEverywhere (following the instructions from [HoloEverywhere's github](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE#eclipse)), and apparently [the latest version is incompatible with ABS](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/650).  I used HoloEverywhere v1.6.8 instead, and everything works :)  Thanks for the help Gaurav!

Answer (score 8):

It seems that

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock"
```

cause an error.

change it:

```
android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme"
```

resons here:

[Github](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/57)

correct!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error on my project, This is what I did, right click the HoloEverywhere (properties->android->library) remove the ActionBarSherlock from the list then re-add the ActionBarSherlock project by click add, after that clean up the project and all errors will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

The creator of ActionBarSherlock, Jake Wharton, announced on Google+ that further development of ActionBarSherlock has been stopped. ActionBarSherlock 4.4 is the last release and might get bug fixes – but there won’t be any new features:

> While there may be a dot release or two in the coming weeks, version
>   4.4 is shaping up to be The Last Release™.

https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/F3HkWY9J8fK

As i asked on [holoeverywhere issues forum](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/742) and answered by devs:

> HoloEverywhere doesn't have any dependency with ABS since v2.0

So you should not use ABS anymore and remove the library from your project and replace it holoeverywhere directly or with ActionbarCompat from google support library.