# Adding HoloEverywhere. Library is Empty

Tags: android, android-layout, android-holo-everywhere

I am currently coding an application then decided to add HoloEverywhere into my application. However when I go to Properties > Android > Add.

It's empty. Am I doing anything wrong?

Do I need to do anything beforehand?

[image]

Comment: Try this, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608539/error-importing-holoeverywhere

Comment: I've used Rawkode's method and it works. Thanks anyway! I've read that and it doesn't work. That's why I start a new topic. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import HoloEverywhere into your workspace first as a library project. You can do this by clicking on File -> Import