# Android Action bar Background

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been trying to change the background of my action bar for quite some time now. I found some posts here of users who could change the background but not the text color. In my example this is the contrary as the background is giving me problems.

I have not created any dynamic design from my activity.

The following is my style.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>  
</style>     

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
<item name="android:background">#FD5200</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">#FD5200</item>
</style>
```

Any knows what might be causing this?

Comment: Try adding items with names `android:backgroundStacked` and `android:backgroundSplit`

Comment: Thank, turns out I was setting the background dynamically through a line of code which I deleted a number of times yet Ctrl+Z popped it up again without knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `ActionBarSherlock` a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888882/932307) may help you going.