# Error importing Holo everywhere theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I have followed the the guides on few sites and I cannot get it to work.  I made sure they I created the project from existing source, and include as libraries in my project, checked targets, etc.    I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I get the following errors:

```
[2012-08-29 21:04:45 - IT Guru] C:\Workspace\HoloEverywhereLib\res\values\styles.xml:246: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
[2012-08-29 21:04:45 - IT Guru] C:\Workspace\HoloEverywhereLib\res\values\styles.xml:247: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
[2012-08-29 21:04:45 - IT Guru] C:\Workspace\HoloEverywhereLib\res\values-v14\styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock'.
[2012-08-29 21:04:45 - IT Guru] C:\Workspace\HoloEverywhereLib\res\values-v14\styles.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.
[2012-08-29 21:04:45 - IT Guru] C:\Workspace\HoloEverywhereLib\res\values-v14\styles.xml:16: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2012-08-29 21:04:45 - IT Guru] C:\Workspace\HoloEverywhereLib\res\values-v14\styles.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow'.
[2012-08-29 21:04:45 - IT Guru] C:\Workspace\HoloEverywhereLib\res\values-v14\styles.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow'.
[2012-08-29 21:46:56 - IT Guru] C:\Workspace\HoloEverywhereLib\res\values\styles.xml:247: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock'.
[2012-08-29 21:46:56 - IT Guru] C:\Workspace\HoloEverywhereLib\res\values\styles.xml:253: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereLight.Sherlock'.
```

Guides Followed:

[Error importing HoloEverywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608539/error-importing-holoeverywhere)

https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 3):

The HoloEverywhere guide you linked to is a small bit out-of-date, the two themes are now called `Holo.Theme` and `Holo.Theme.Light`.

So change these lines in your Android manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock"
```

or

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereLight.Sherlock"
```

to

```
 android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme"
```

or

```
android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Light"
```

Then Project->Clean and see if the errors disappear.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Sherlock theme(Not integrated Android Theme) you need to import that additional package under ProjectName/ folder

+ProjectName

1. src
2. gen
3. Android2.1
4. Sherlock.jar(Import tht .jar file under root Folder)
5. bin
6. . . .

Comment: I wasn't planning on using the sherlock actionbar, but I included following the guide and I think that is where the errors are coming from.  I couldn't find a sherlock.jar, just import from existing code, make library, and include library.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the android target of all the projects to the newest android version (v.17 atm)

Comment: Even @georgiecasey answer is correct. If you take the latest update then the theme names have changed.

Comment: Oops i thought you were the original author sorry.