# Adding Holo theme to 2.3.6/Error using HoloEverywhere

Tags: android

How can i use holoeverywhere in my app?

i have the following error when adding library to my project,the
guide folllowed:

[Error importing HoloEverywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608539/error-importing-holoeverywhere)

```
`[2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:spinnerMode'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:63: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:70: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:73: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupWindow'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:258: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:animationResolution'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:78: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:85: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:90: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:328: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:96: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:98: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:100: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:102: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:104: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:106: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:117: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:119: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:22: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:196: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:197: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:198: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Dialog'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:222: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:223: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values\abs__themes.xml:224: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside'.
 [2012-12-05 20:23:11 - com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic] C:\Users\aditya\workspace\ActionBarSherlock\library\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog'.`
```

---

### Or tell me if there another easy way to add Holo dark theme to app running on 2.3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't solve your problem yet I've found solution for it. I've done it on DemoActivity app provided with HoloEverywhere, but I think it won't be a problem to use it in your app also.

The most important thing is to **import all libarary projects**, the order isn't important:

- HoloEverywhere library from library folder
- Slidingmenu from slidingmenu folder
- ActionBarSherlock library from contrib/ActionBarSherlock library

First close all projects that are not related, because then errors/warnings from them will disappear from problems console, so it is easier to find those connected to HoloEverywhere.

After, be sure that you have in all Manifest files

`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />`

you can even change 16 to 17 as it is newest SDK. The shortest possible explanation of this line mean, that this app can be run on any Android device with SDK above 7 and below 16.

Then, for all added libraries change **project build target** for the highest possible (I put 4.2). I think at least it has to be SDK14 (4.0). You will see that the target has been changed because in project tree you will have folder with proper android target library. I have to warn you, that change of this folder may take a minute or two - keep watching progress bar.

How to change project build target:

Right mouse button on project name -> properties [on the bottom almost of the list] (or when project name is highlighted on menu bar project-> properties)
In opened window left panel -> Android -> right panel and choose correct target. Then Apply and OK.

The last thing is to **clean each project** (again it may take a while especially if you have as I have auto building option on):
Menu bar->Project->Clean->select all projects related to this (if you closed all not related than you should see only projects for this application) and than OK.

Thanks to this you will have your R file rebuild with things that were added in higher SDK, so then you can refer to them in code.

Now you shouldn't have any more errors, only warnings.

If you still have some problems comment it below and maybe I will be able to help you.

To show that it is working there you go screenshots from actual device running Android 2.3.4

[image: 2.3.4 HoloEverywhere DemoActivity]
[image: 2.3.4 HoloEverywhere DemoActivity]

If this was helpful, or is answer for your question don't forget to mark it properly.

Comment: while referencing i accidently did something and i got stackoverflow , unable to parsesdk errors

Comment: i manually removed all references from project.properties... not to mention Very Very thnx for your support

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been struggling with this problem for a few hours now and thanks to you, I have finally solved it!

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove all projects from your workspace;
2. Import ActionBarSherlock;
3. Import HoloEverywhere;
4. Import your project;
5. Ensure that HoloEverywhere is referencing ActionBarSherlock and yours is referencing HoloEverywhere (you can do that by accessing *project properties* -> *Android* -> *Library* -> *Add*);
6. Disable *Project* -> *Build automatically*;
7. Clean all projects (remember to uncheck *Start build immediately*);
8. Right-click ActionBarSherlock project and then *Build project*;
9. Do the same for HoloEverywhere and yours, respectively.

You have to build each project separately, according to their order of dependence.

Comment: can you explain step 5... sorry as i am a  newbie

Comment: Check this out, from 3.6 and on: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html#tutorial_library_usage

Comment: everything worked correct until i built `ActionBarSherlock` and it gave me errors(100 of 211 items) and warnings(18 items)... so i didn't proceed further or built `Holo Everywhere` or my Project..

Comment: Check project.properties of both libs. Set target to the highest possible: `target=android-17`.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't works... but ver thanks for your support