# IntelliJ ActionBar styling - resource not found

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-actionbar

In my app i finally decided to get rid of ActionBarSherlock. In order to do that i had to fix some of my styles. When compiling app with styles like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyAppDropDownStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppDropDownStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

IntelliJ Idea throws error `Error:(50, -1) android-apt-compiler: [MyApp] C:\SLI\Repo\Android\MyApp\res\values\themes.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar'.`. IntelliJ can find this resource by "Go to > declaration" option. Any idea how to fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your build target? 11 or 13?

Comment: minSdkVersion is 14, target 20.

Comment: if the solution on this link is your answer, tell me, to put it as answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726018/adding-holo-theme-to-2-3-6-error-using-holoeverywhere

Comment: Unfortunately this link doesn't solve my problem. Missing resource isn't related to any third-party library. They are included in a standard android styles.xml file. Moreover other styles from the same file are linked the same way and they don't cause the error.

Comment: please do it, and tell me:
Project(Right Click)--> Android Tools --> Add Support Library / Fix Project Property.

Comment: I assume this option is available only under Eclipse? I am using IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: Please set second parent to this: Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar` is private and I couldn't use it in inheritance. Displayed error was somewhat misleading - it told that resource wasn't found at all. I found last public ancestor of this style and filled it with required information, so the solution looks like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyAppDropDownStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppDropDownStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
   <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

It's really simple, but relatively hard to find.