# Error using HoloEverywhere in the last step

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to use HoloEveryWhere with ABS. I followed this little tutorial from an answer: [Error importing HoloEverywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608539/error-importing-holoeverywhere/10888882#10888882)

The last step says to add this in my manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock">
```

I've added the theme, but it gives me an error in Eclipse.

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/
 Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock').
```

How do I go about fixing that? I definitely have ABS and HE imported as libraries in my app. I also have ABS imported as a library in HE. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use @style/Holo.Theme

Since 1.3 (?) theme names was be changed to Holo.Theme[.Light[.DarkActionBar]].Sherlock.
Since 1.4 removed postfix .Sherlock.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the manifest to below

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

It work like charm