# HoloEverywhere error: build path contains duplicate entry src

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I'm developing an app currently which shall use ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere however whenever I try to import the HoloEverywhere library into eclipse I get the following error:

Build path contains duplicate entry: 'src' in project 'library'

I have checked the library folder and there is no duplicate in it but it still complains.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check ``.classpath`` file at project root. It might be the case there's duplicate entry for src directory.

Comment: I am sorry, but i could not find that file anywhere in the project

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I'm still struggling with it.

Comment: I'm getting this error too!

Comment: Did you try the solution given below, actually i removed the error mentioned above by using that. But after that, i had to deal with some more errors, which i couldn't get removed.

Answer (score 9):

This is how mine solved:

property->resource->Android, tick an Android build target then click OK

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue,

try this:

Just import it with the duplicate src error, then right click on the HoloeEverywhere library project and select properties. In properties select Android (on the left) and under Project Build Target check if the Target Name Android 4.2 (or whatever yours is) is checked. Mine wasn't. If you check it, it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Both projects "HoloEverywhere" and "ActionBarSherlock" has name "library". So, you probably should rename them. Then import both projects (ignore HoloEverywhere error). Choose "Android option" in "HoloEverywhere" project properties. Remove all bad references and add new reference to "ActionBarSherlock" project library.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you have to right click on the project name on the left hand side and choose properties, then choose Android and add a tick to the Build target e.g Android 4.0, don't forget to apply and click ok afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the HoloEverywhere project, go to Android, in the Library section, removes the selected and them select the ActionBarSherlock library that already is in your workspace.

Comment: I have removed the error and i still get many errors when run, even not changing the code. I am using Eclipse Juno. has this anything to do with. Because i have seen on the web there are problems importing holoeveywhere.

Comment: Could you describe better the errors that are you dealing now?

Answer (score 0):

No obvious duplications in path and after hours of trying various suggestions, I change the target (in both the project properties and manifest) from 15 to 17 to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

To fix it, open .classpath file in your project home directory and comment out any one of the following two lines

> < classpathentrykind="src"path="onePath"/>
>    
>   < classpathentrykind="src"path="anotherpath"/>

here one and another Paths are the paths that are referencing your library.

Then, right click the Project->Android Tools-> Fix Project Properties. Then clean and build your project.

Comment: I am sorry, but i could not find that file anywhere in the project

Comment: i said project home directory it means the folder in your workspace in which your project is saved.

Comment: <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
 <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/classes" path="src">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
 </classpathentry>
 <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/classes" path="test">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
 </classpathentry>

Comment: i removed this,   <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/classes" path="src"> <attributes> <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/> </attributes> </classpathentry> <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/classes" path="test"> <attributes> <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/> </attributes> </classpathentry>

Comment: <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/classes" path="test"> <attributes> <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/> </attributes> </classpathentry>

remove this.

Comment: keep all otherthings as it is.