# HoloEverywhere error when importing library - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I try to import HoloEverywhere's library folder into my workspace via Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Build path contains duplicate entry: 'src' in project 'library'
```

Doing some research, I found this thread: [HoloEverywhere error: build path contains duplicate entry src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278884/holoeverywhere-error-build-path-contains-duplicate-entry-src)
One of the suggestions is to edit the .classpath file located in the library folder and then proceed importing this same folder. However, now when importing I get the following errors:

```
Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
AndroidManifest.xml file missing!
```

I have searched all over Stackoverflow and Google and can't find a solution to this. I have tried to fix the project properties via Eclipse to no avail.

Any thoughts on this would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same issue, no answer yet...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turns out I had referenced in the HoloEverywhere library (which references the ActionbarSherlock library), and the ActionBarSherlock library.

So basically HoloEverywhere already uses ABS, so you remove ABS from your own project. Also check to make sure HoloEverywhere is referencing ABS correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue,

try this:

Just import it with the duplicate src error, then right click on the HoloeEverywhere library project and select properties. In properties select Android (on the left) and under Project Build Target check if the Target Name Android 4.2 (or whatever yours is) is checked. Mine wasn't. If you check it, it should fix the problem.