# Prototik HoloEverywhere import error: duplicate entry 'src'

Tags: android, eclipse, build, android-holo-everywhere

I have already looked at :
[HoloEverywhere error: build path contains duplicate entry src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278884/holoeverywhere-error-build-path-contains-duplicate-entry-src)

I am using this version of holoeverywhere:
https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

I have tried everything that everyone has suggested there, but nothing has worked yet. The person who asked the question didn't come back to pick the answer either.

I'm trying to import the Prototik HoloEverwhere into my Eclipse (from Androi ADT), but it keeps giving me errors, and is unusable. 
This is what the error looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW3te.png

This is what it says:
"Build path contains duplicate entry: 'src' for project 'HoloEverywhere Library'"

Comment: rename the project to something else like just Holo and try importing again

Comment: It installs as /HoloEverywhere Library. I'm not sure how to rename it since the folder doesn't actually say "/HoloEverywhere Library"

Comment: Can you share the url where you downloaded the library from, so i can try in my conputer and see whats going on

Comment: @Peshal i tried renaming it now through .project, still the same issue.

Comment: @Peshal, i'm using this: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Comment: Is there a different holoeverywhere version I should be using?

Comment: the link you have should be the right one. I remember i had several issues with this library until i finally figured out. Its been a while since i last used it, so lets see what i can do.

Comment: Alright, i have the same issue however i was able to import it using GIT. Do you know how to import using GIT

Comment: Oh, okay. I only have the Androit ADT Eclipse bundle, so I don't know how to install the GIT using the marketplace. Is there a way I can still install that through "Install New Software" ?

Comment: When you click on File menu in eclipse and select import do you see GIT in the list

Comment: @Peshal yes i do see Git! It worked perfectly! You're a life saver. Please put it as the answer to the question, so I can select your answer. Thank you so much again!!

Comment: @Peshal Import worked flawless, but I'm getting

Description Resource Path Location Type
The field DateUtils.LENGTH_MEDIUM is deprecated DatePicker.java /HoloEverywhere Library/src/org/holoeverywhere/widget line 457 Java Problem

There are just a few problems with the library that are showing up.How did you clear them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok As mentioned in the comment: Import the HoloEverywhere using File> Import> Git > Projects from Git