# Configuring ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to configure ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere following https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888882/2031219.

However, in the step 6 and 7, when I click on Android heading in the properties of the project my Eclipse stop works.

which may be the problem?

Thanks