# Android HoloEverywhere: mChildFragmentManager cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608539/error-importing-holoeverywhere/10888882#10888882) closely and successfully added ActionBarSherlock lib to both my project and HoloEverywhere. However when I built the HoloEverywhere library I got these errors:

In *android.support.v4.app* package, _HoloFragment.java:

```
mChildFragmentManager cannot be resolved to a variable
```

In *android.support.v4.app* package, _HoloFragmentInflater.java:

```
mParentFragment cannot be resolved or is not a field

The method moveToState(Fragment, int, int, int) in the type FragmentManagerImpl is not applicable for the arguments (Fragment, int, int, int, boolean)

The method getChildFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Fragment
```

I tried almost everything to get it working but no success. Please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to update the support library v4 in your `ActionBarSherlock` library to revision 11 or revision 12.

You can do this by downloading the latest revision in the SDK manager. Go to SDK Manager > Extras and then download `Android Support Library.`

In your Android directory, go to `\extras\android\support\v4` and copy `android-support-v4.jar` from here into your `ActionBarSherlock` library. `HoloEverywhere` should now build fine.

I had the same error and posted the issue here:

[mChildFragmentManager cannot be resolved to a variable](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/353)

Comment: well I'm already using support lib v13. you are talking about this right: android-support-v13.jar?

Comment: No, support library version 4, revision 11 or 12 in the ActionBarSherlock project

Comment: Getting the above error on the latest version of the holoEverywhere library.

i read how you need to update the android support library from action bar sherlock. how can you do that when HoloEverywhere automatically pulls action bar sherlock?

One way i see is that to manually just download the src code for holoeverwhere and actiobar and make the changes there but that defeats the purpose of just calling this library from the pom files dependency?

Can you commit and push this update for us so that the library has the fix?