# Troubles while importing HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I'm following this guide:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888882/1943607

> Follow the steps below to add HoloEverywhere
>
> Download Zip from GitHub to your computer UnZip the folder Go to
>   eclipse and choose File->New-> Android Project
>
> Select Create project from existing source and then browse to the HoloEverywhereLib folder
>   inside extracted folder
>
> Press Finish
>
> Right click on the newly created project and go to Properties. Under the Android heading, you should see a section for Library with a checkbox IsLibrary. Make sure that's checked and press Add and previously added library ActionBarSherlock.

I unzipped the folder. Then went to eclipse -> Right click -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace.
I select the unzipped folder and It's showing this:
[image]

When I click Finish:
[image]

And then if I create a new project, and try to import it, It cant find the library; I type `org.` and it isn't showing up the rest (org.holoeverywhere.app.***Activity). (Like its github says https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere#how-to-use-maven)

Can you help me out?

**Edit: I've also tried to remove src from .classpath files with same result**

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository using Github desktop.  Install eGit on Eclipse.  Then use import-->Git-->Projects from Git.