# "Error: No resource found that matches the given name" HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I imported HoloEverywhere following this guide:

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE

and this guide:

[Error importing HoloEverywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608539/error-importing-holoeverywhere)

I checked my libs reference i check my build target to be the highest i checked everything

but still i got this error when loading the projects:

```
[2013-06-25 23:26:50 - HoloEverywhere Demo] G:\Programs\HoloEverywhere\library\res\values\themes-core.xml:72: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listPopupWindowStyle'.
```

I got this error for many more "attr" i just posted here on of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this because of your android dependency version , i was getting the same error when a newly created api level 14 project has been turned to api level 10 or 8 from project properties .As this api level doesn't have holo theme and style it gives me error in all style xml files and menu files .I think this might be the case with yours too .