# Error in pom when implementing HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I have been able to follow these steps here 
[Error importing HoloEverywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608539/error-importing-holoeverywhere/10888882#10888882)

but I keep getting this error in the pom.xml on the ....

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.holoeverywhere:parent:pom:1.6.9-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

Can anyone help me regarding this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a change in the pom.xml after google code evalution..

Just replace the whole pom.xml with this one https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/blob/8b387bf87beeafa1f9ed762ff6812fec596a6b5b/pom.xml