# Attribute duplication importing HoloEverywhere and ActionbarSherlock in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I have been struggling with this problem for hours now. I have tried all tips I found at StackOverflow, but they did not help me.

The problem:

I have imported HoloEverywhere in Eclipse. I then imported ActionbarSherlock into HoloEverywhere, as is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888882/2566395) only to get a bunch of errors. Also, R.java is not being generated for the HoloEverywhere project (I tried cleaning all projects, didn't work).

Judging by the log output, I'd say there are repeating attribute names in the ActionbarSherlock and HoloEverywhere projects. How do I fix that?

Here is part of the log:

`[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:30: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowMinWidthMajor'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:31: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowMinWidthMinor'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values\themes.xml:152: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:43: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:activatedBackgroundIndicator'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:44: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dialogTheme'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerHorizontal'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:46: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerVertical'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:48: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:49: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowMinWidthMajor'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values-v11\themes.xml:50: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowMinWidthMinor'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values\themes.xml:188: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values\themes.xml:238: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2013-09-18 02:34:22 - library] D:\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values\themes.xml:274: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.`

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19113424/1102276, you must use v1.6.8 for the HoloEverywhere library in order to get rid of the errors (https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/releases/tag/v1.6.8)

Answer (score 0):

keep actionbar sherlock part of holoeverywhere library but remove it from the actual app project i had the same issue and that fixed it. Also make sure the android-support library is the same across the board.