# conflict between ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, conflict, android-support-library, android-holo-everywhere

i would like to use these libraries together in my project, but after i added these ones in my project, i got some errors.

1)i did ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere as libraries.

2)i attached ActionBarSherlock library in the HoloEverywhere library.

3)i attached HoloEverywhere library in  my project.

4)left only one library android-support-v4.jar in ActionBarSherlock.

Errors i've got:

```
D:\projects\android\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values\abc_attrs.xml:32: error: Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
D:\projects\android\HoloEverywhere-master\library\res\values\abc_attrs.xml:33: error: Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
and etc.
```

how can i rid of these errors?
thanks!

Comment: I believe you can just delete these lines (windowActionBar and windowActionBarOverlay) as they are already defined by ActionBarSherlock

Comment: what error does it give if you just delete those lines?

Answer (score 3):

Currently (October 2013) use v1.6.8 of HoloEverywhere. See [Github issue #650](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/650).